# How to SELECT Date and TIme from Date time column using ON Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a join query

```
SELECT  vs.Id as 'VitalId', ms.PatientId as 'PatientId',  ms.CustomerId  as 'CustomerId', ms.CreatedUtc
from A1 a
join B1 b
    on a.CreatedUtc = b.concat(concat(convert(date,S.CreatedUtc),':'),
                               datepart(hour,S.CreatedUtc))
```

Actually i want to map a.CreatedUtc to date and time to b table (i.e:- B2). 
Is this query work.? because when i run this query no records are inserted.

Can any one tell me how to take only Date and time from Datetime column using ON Clause?

Comment: Please show sample data and table structure for both tables.

Comment: Whatever the schema and actual question is, there's *no* reason to use string operations on dates. If any of the `CreatedUtc` is text, the real problem is the bad data type, not the join expression. In *both* cases it's impossible to use indexes on those fields making queries very slow

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select vs.Id as VitalId, ms.PatientId as PatientId,  
       ms.CustomerId  as CustomerId, ms.CreatedUtc
from A1 a join
     B1 b
     on convert(date, a.CreatedUtc) = convert(date, S.CreatedUtc) and
        datepart(hour, a.CreatedUtc) = datepart(hour, S.CreatedUtc);
```

Comment: Not exactly.. I  don't want datepart.. is it possible to achieve date and hour in single row.?